# how to call class before define it

Tags: scala

I'm new in Scala and start by reading [Scala By Example](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf) book,

there is an issue in that book and I couldn't understand it, for example on page 59, the author wrote:

```
abstract class Stack[+A] {
  def push[B >: A](x: B): Stack[B] = new NonEmptyStack(x, this)
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def top: A
  def pop: Stack[A]
}
object EmptyStack extends Stack[Nothing] {
  def isEmpty = true
  def top = error("EmptyStack.top")
  def pop = error("EmptyStack.pop")
}
class NonEmptyStack[+A](elem: A, rest: Stack[A]) extends Stack[A] {
  def isEmpty = false
  def top = elem
  def pop = rest
}
```

as you see *NonEmptyStack(x, this)* class called before defining.
how is it possible?

when i try those codes i encountered below compiler message:

> < console>:11: error: not found: type NonEmptyStack
>           def push[B >: A](x: B): Stack[B] = new NonEmptyStack(x, this)

Comment: Well.... the thing is that Scala is actually a compiled language and the compiler finds the class as long as it is available inside the project or the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was [Sarvesh Kumar Singh's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783938/how-to-call-class-before-define-it#comment64944844_38783938):

> Well.... the thing is that Scala is actually a compiled language and the compiler finds the class as long as it is available inside the project or the classpath. – Sarvesh Kumar Singh Aug 5 at 10:51

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `:paste`then copy the code to allow the Scala REPL to evaluate the whole block of code.

Comment: thanks but 1-in OOP issue,how is it possible(use before definition),2-i could not understand your answer, could you please more explain?